# plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick" (CMake)

Tags: qt, cmake, qtquick2, vcpkg

I have installed Qt using vcpkg and successfully managed to get a QtWidgets application working.

I created a default QtQuick application using QtCreator and the QtCreator Qt binaries and it runs just fine. However, when transferring over to VS Code (which is using vcpkg for its Qt binaries) I get the following error in my console and the application exits:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:1:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick": Cannot load library F:\Projects\Dev\Qt-Creator\QtQuickCMakeTest-vscode\build\MSVC-2019-x64\Debug\Debug\qml\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugind.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

However when navigating to the specified location, the file "qtquick2plugind.dll" is indeed there. Looking in the debug console of VS Code I get the following:

```
Loaded 'F:\Projects\Dev\Qt-Creator\QtQuickCMakeTest-vscode\build\MSVC-2019-x64\Debug\Debug\qml\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugind.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Unloaded 'F:\Projects\Dev\Qt-Creator\QtQuickCMakeTest-vscode\build\MSVC-2019-x64\Debug\Debug\qml\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugind.dll'.
```

Why is it loading and unloading the qtquick2plugind.dll? I assuming the loading process is failing, but why?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt, although it is exactly the same as the default Qt Creator one for Qt Quick, except I am passing a path to my vcpkg toolchain which CMake ultimately uses to find Qt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(QtQuickCMakeTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(Qt5 ...) call.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick QuickControls2 QuickTemplates2 REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "CURRENT VAR ${Qt5_DIR}")

if(ANDROID)
    add_library(QtQuickCMakeTest SHARED
      main.cpp
      qml.qrc
    )
else()
    add_executable(QtQuickCMakeTest
      main.cpp
      qml.qrc
    )
endif()

target_compile_definitions(QtQuickCMakeTest
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(QtQuickCMakeTest
  PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::QuickControls2 Qt5::QuickTemplates2)
```

The application is running, so I am not getting linking errors, but the QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated hooked returns my QObject as nullptr, causing QCoreApplication::exit(-1); to be called.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that CMake/Qt was not copying all the required DLLs to the bin folder of my project.

After a bunch of trial and error, I figured out that the following three DLLs were required but were not present:

- Qt5QmlModelsd.dll
- Qt5QmlWorkerScriptd.dll
- Qt5Quickd.dll

The strange thing is that other DLLs (such as Qt5Qmld.dll) **were** copied correctly, so now the next step in this process is determining why these specific DLLs aren't being copied and how to make it automated as it should be, so help on this would still be greatly appreciated.